# Ajax inside Ajax somehow strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a Ajax-Call inside a Ajax-Call, everything "seems" to work fine. In console I can see, both calls are executed and get a return.

But somehow, i can't use the returned result from the second call(?)

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "register/checkEmail/"+email,                 
            success: function(result){

                if(result == "TRUE") {                    
                    $('#regMsg').html('Ein User mit dieser Email ist bereits registriert!');
                    $('#regMsg').slideDown();  

                // NO ERROR - REGISTER USER
                } else {                        
                    $('#regMsg').slideUp();            
                    var inputs = $('#regForm :input').serializeArray();

                    alert('ok');  
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "register/save",
                        data: inputs,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(result){
                             alert('ddok'); 
                        }
                    });

                }                    

            }
        });
```

the first `alert()` is beeing displayed, the secont is not, although the second call is executed correctly(?) why is that?

Comment: Use Firebug or the Chrome Inspector to verify that the second call returned a success.

Comment: I would check network in chrome devtools to see if second POST to register/save is correctly being resolved by the service.

Comment: Where is `inputs` defined? Try including `error` option at second `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: hey .. 1) `inputs` is defined just above the second ajax-call .. 2) yes, i can verity in the inspector, that the second ajax-call deliveres a `200 OK` and also a HTML-output.. but whatever I try, everything inside the second-ajax's- success() just won't work

Comment: Is `result` value of first `$.ajax()` call `"TRUE"`?

Comment: @guest271314 it's not equal because he said it triggers the first alert and because he said second ajax is not working, read again

Comment: @Almis .. second ajax IS working .. i can see that the request is been sent and gets something back..what is not working, is everything inside the second ajax's success-function

Comment: @Almis Including an error handler at second `$.ajax()` call could reveal if second request is successful. The issue could also be reproduced at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co .

Comment: @braz you have two alerts so it will show only the first one and after clicking ok it will show the second one, are you saying that after clicking ok on first one it doesn't show the second one?

Comment: @Almaz .. exactly

Comment: Using `alert()` blocks the JS thread. Try logging to the console instead.

Comment: I would do a console.log() instead of an alert.  My guess is that the browser is preventing the 2nd alert to avoid "spamming" alerts.

Comment: Cannot reproduce https://fiddle.jshell.net/8xot4rao/2/

Comment: @guest271314 on fiddle it's working fine, maybe you have adblock?

Comment: @Almis _"on fiddle it's working fine"_ Yes. Cannot reproduce issue described at Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple - the second call's response did not return back to the ajax i.e error/fail.

Add the **error** handling part after **success** to find the response.
After success add

```
,error: function(result){
    alert('error'); 
    console.log(result);
}
```

If this is not the reason, then **dataType: 'json',** should be the culprit as your response wouldn't be in json format !!

Comment: hi, .. how do you mean that?  .. I added the error-handling to the second ajax and it returns me `({readyState:4, getResponseHeader:(fun...return this}), responseText:"kkkkkreg success", status:200, statusText:"OK"})`

Comment: Your responseText:"kkkkkreg success"
But your AJAX expects it to be **dataType: 'json',**

Comment: if you had handled error you could have seen this !! now either send a data in json format or remove the dataType from the ajax code

Comment: dude!! .. that was it!! -.- .. thank you :))  ,., i think i need to go to sleep for some hours :D

Comment: you're welcome - please mark the answer helpful if it was